# Contradiction to Bolzano Weierstraß Theorem?

Tags: convergence-divergence

Consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} = 2+ \frac{1}{n}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ with the metric
$$d(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
|x-1| + |y-1|&\text{if $x\neq y$}\\
0 &\text{if $x=y$}
\end{cases}
$$
Then one is able to show that this is a bounded sequence but it cannot possess a convergent subsequence. So my question is: why is this not a contradiction to the Bolzano Weierstraß Theorem for $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\mathbb{C}$ understood as $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: $d$ is not a metric because $d(x,x)$ should be zero.

Comment: Even if $d$ were a metric, the Bolzano−Weierstraß theorem applies for the usual topology of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: The metric that you propose is not equivalent to the topology of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Choose $A=[\pi+e, \pi e]$ in $(\Bbb{Q}, d_{\text{std}}) $.Then $A$ is closed and bounded but not compact or choose any infinite discrete space.

Comment: The subspace $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{1\}$ of $(\mathbb{C}, d)$ is discrete.  It's not surprising that a bounded sequence in a discrete space doesn't have a convergent subsequence.  (As others have said, Bolzano-Weierstrass doesn't apply to every metrizable topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$, just the usual one)

Comment: Simple example, choose $X=\Bbb{R}$ and $d(x, y) =0 $ if $x=y$ and $1$ otherwise. $\\$ In this metric $[0, 1]$ is closed and bounded but not compact.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!